# How to create an Athena stack and consume Glue Data catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I have to create an athena template in cloud formation, the task is to replicate the next Terraform script using CF:

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "sample_athena_wg" {
  name = "sample_athena_wg"
}

resource "aws_athena_database" "sample_athena_database" {
  name   = "sample_athena_database"
  bucket = "sample_bucket_id"
}

resource "aws_athena_named_query" "test_query" {
  name      = "Test"
  workgroup = aws_athena_workgroup.sample_athena_wg.id
  database  = aws_athena_database.sample_athena_database.name
  query     = "SELECT * FROM ${aws_athena_database.sample_athena_database.name} limit 10;"
}
```

The problem is that there is no such a resource in CF called "AWS::ATHENA::DATABASE" or something like that, and I don't really know what the terraform resource "aws_athena_database" is creating behind the scenes. When I deploy the Terraform script, it seems like this creates a glue database, but I do know what else this creates.

Comment: From the docs:

"Currently, all regions that support Athena also support AWS Glue Data Catalog. Databases and tables are available to Athena using the AWS Glue Data Catalog and vice versa.

If you created databases and tables using Athena or Amazon Redshift Spectrum prior to a region's support for AWS Glue, you can upgrade Athena to use the AWS Glue Data Catalog."

Answer (score 0):

I found that Terraform creates an Athena Workgroup and GLue database behind the scenes when you try to create a aws_athena_database. I could replicate this resource in CF like this:

```
 AthenaWorkgroup:
    Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
    Properties:
      Name: ....
      State: ENABLEDr
      WorkGroupConfiguration:
        BytesScannedCutoffPerQuery: ...
        EnforceWorkGroupConfiguration: ...
        PublishCloudWatchMetricsEnabled: ...
        ResultConfiguration:
          OutputLocation: !Ref S3LocationPath

  GlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      DatabaseInput:
        Name: ...
```